# jquery selectors and Asp.net dynamic controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I create a group of RadioButtons dynamically and then I want to get the one selected in javascript.

The controls are created as follows:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();
    var rb = new RadioButton {GroupName = "group1"};

    this.availableActions.Controls.Add(rb);
    ................
}
```

Then, on the page, I'm doing:

```
$(document).ready(function () { alert($('input[name=group1]')); });
```

The alert shows null. I can't figure out why...
I inspected the code in chrome, the radio buttons are in the page.

```
<p id="availableActions" class="download_options">
    <input id="rb_0" type="radio" name="group1" value="rb_0" checked="checked">
    .....
```

Any ideas?

Important to note that this code is in an iframe that is generated by prettyPhoto jquery plugin. I wonder if this is the source of problems....

Thanks in advance

Comment: jQuery selectors do not return null if there's no match they return an empty selection so is that what you are seeing or is it something else that returns null?

Comment: Please post (a snippet of ) the generated html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has this problem, the solution was to change jQuery to no conflict mode.

I'm not sure what was causing the conflict because `$(document).ready(function () { console.log('loaded'); });` was working fine but I couldn't find any control on the page.

To change to no conflict mode just add `jQuery.noConflict();` and change the $ to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be totally correct. It would be better if u share your html here. Try to use console.log instead of alert and check your firebug console that element is returning or not.

Comment: The html is quite large... This also shows null in the console: $(document).ready(function () { console.log($('input[@name=group1]')); });

Answer (score 0):

it's unclear what you mean by `create dynamically`if you create the mdynamically on the client then you are better of using `.on`to do the binding

```
$("availableActions").on("change","input[name=group1",function(){
    ///do what ever you wish
});
```

Comment: Dynamic on the server. But I added a static radiobutton in the client and is still not loaded. I wonder if this is related with jquery's PrettyPhoto plugin...